# How to dynamically populate a dropdown field on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dropdownbox

I need some help on how to populate a dropdown that is dynamically created based on the length of an array. If the length is 4 it needs to populate in all 4 created dropdown options.

This is my html code

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="addBtn">
    </div>
<div class="form-control" id="bookTemplate">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="Merc">Merc</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Javascript looks like this

```
var myCars = [
    "Jaguar",
    "Limo", 
    "BMW", 
    "Ford Mustang",
     "Audi"
     ];

    for (var i = 0; <myCars.length; i++) {
        $(".addBtn").click()
    }
    $('.myPopulatedValueElements').each(function(index){
        var carCounter = 0;
        var optionCounter = 0;
        $(this).find('option').each(function(){
            if($(this)[optionCounter] == myCars[carCounter]){
                $(this)[optionCounter].attr('selected', 'selected')
                carCounter ++
            }else{
                optionCounter++
            }

        });
    });
```

What happens is that it adds new dropdown fields based on the array length but it does not populate on each added field with the array elements. Any help on what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: It's slightly confusing what you are after.  Looking at the markup, you only have one select.  Looking at you're logic, you're clicking the addBtn the same number of times that there are cars in your array, but that doesn't appear to have any associated logic with that click event, so it's unclear why you are doing that.

Comment: Can you please rewrite this part? It's not very clear to me: "What happens is that it adds new dropdown fields based on the array length but it does not populate on each added field with the array elements."

Comment: @Taplar the bookTemplate is a hidden part of the form with dropdown that get displayed on button click, those ones are is just the placeholder kinda thing.  so the logic is with the length of the array I'm expecting to something like <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>
            </select>
            <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="Limo">Limo</option>
            </select> etc

Comment: @Adriano it does add new dropdown field after looping through the for loop I have there, each time it loop it add one dropdown field until it gets to five. The problem I have is that it doesn't populate in the fields with the array elements

Comment: Wait, are you saying you are creating select elements with a single option in them?

Comment: @Taplar no the can be all in it, what I'm trying to achieve is that each and everytime the button click the array element has to be selected  <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="Jaguar" selected="selected">Jaguar</option>
                <option value="Limo">Limo</option>
            </select>
            <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="Limo" selected="selected"> Limo</option>
                <option value="Ford Mustang">Ford Mustang</option>
            </select> something like that

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off with two points of invalid syntax:

- You're missing the `i` before the `<` in your `for` loop
- You're missing the text and closing tag for your `button`

Now assuming what you want is to populate the `<select>` dropdown with `<option>` elements comprised of your `myCars` array, what you need to do is:

- Remove the existing `<option>` elements; you're adding the cars in dynamically, so it makes no sense to already have some
- Loop over the `myCars` array, rather than the HTML `<select>`
- For each car, construct an `<option>` element, adding a `value` attribute and `text()` that correlates to the index of the cars array
- Finally, you need to move everything into a function, and attach an `onclick` event handler to your button to launch your function.

This can all be seen in the following:

```js
var myCars = [
  "Jaguar",
  "Limo",
  "BMW",
  "Ford Mustang",
  "Audi"
];

function addCars() {
  $(".myPopulatedValueElements").html('');
  // ^ Optionally reset the `<select>` so that you don't get duplicates
  for (var i = 0; i < myCars.length; i++) {
    var $div = $("<option>", {
      value: myCars[i],
    }).text(myCars[i]);
    $(".myPopulatedValueElements").append($div);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <button type="button" class="addBtn" onclick="addCars()">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="form-control" id="bookTemplate">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for!

Comment: more like that but the problem is that, its adding on the same dropdown field instead of creating a new dropdown each time I click the button like this <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>
            </select>
            <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="Limo">Limo</option>
            </select>
            <select class="myPopulatedValueElements">
                <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
            </select>